# Quasar File Picker doesn't upload image in ios

Tags: ios, vue.js, capacitor, quasar-framework, quasar

I want to implement image uploading. It works for web (Chrome/Safari), but not for mobile ios (built with Capacitor). It shows image selection, but when I select it nothing happens.

Here is my input:

```
    <q-file
      v-model="avatarFile"
      accept=".jpg, .png"
      @input="uploadImage"
    />


async uploadImage() {
 if (this.avatarFile) {
  let extension = "jpg";
  if (this.avatarFile.type === "image/png") {
    extension = "png";
  }
  try {
    this.loading = 1;
    const {
      data: {
        uploadUrl: { uploadUrl },
      },
    } = await this.$apollo.query({
      query: GET_UPLOAD_URL,
      variables: {
        extension,
      },
    });
    await axios.put(uploadUrl, this.avatarFile);
    await setTimeout(() => {
      this.$emit("on-image-upload");
      this.loading = 0;
    }, 3000);
  } catch (e) {
    this.alertError(e);
    this.loading = 0;
  }
 }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. My accept rule had the wrong format. This works:

```
accept="image/*"
```